# How to ingest historical data with proper creation time?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

When ingesting historical data, we would like it to become consistent with streamed data with respect to caching and retention, hence we need to set proper creation time on the data extents.

The options I found:

- `creationTime` [ingestion property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingestion-properties#ingestion-properties),
- `with(creationTime='...')` [query ingestion property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query),
- `creationTimePattern` parameter of [Lightingest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/lightingest#command-line-arguments).

All options seem to have very limited usability as they require manual work or scripting to populate `creationTime` with some granularity based on the ingested data.

In case the "virtual" ingestion time can be extracted from data in form of a datetime column or otherwise inherited (e.g. based on integer ID), is it possible to instruct the engine to set creation time as an expression based on the data row?

If such a feature is missing, what could be other handy alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

*creationTime* is a tag on an extent/shard.
The idea is to be able to **effectively** identify and drop / cool data at the end of the retention time.

In this context, your suggested capability raises some serious issues.
If all records have the same date, no problem, we can use this date as our tag.
If we have different dates, but they span on a short period, we might decide to take min / avg / max date.

However -

What is the behavior you would expect in case of a file that contains dates that span on a long period?
Fail the ingestion?
Use the current time as the *creationTime*?
Use the min / avg / max date, although they clearly don't fit the data well?
Park the records in a tamp store until (if ever) we get enough records with similar dates to create the batches?

---

Scripting seems the most reasonable way to go here.
If your files are indeed homogenous by their records dates, then you don't need to scan all records, just read the 1st record and use its date.

If the dates are heterogenous, then we are at the scenario described by the "However" part.

Comment: Neither of those. As caching and retention is configured in **days**, the data must be chunked on truncated date (or otherwise rounded to day precision) and go into separate extents based on that chunking. The engine can do it on its own or it may require the user to provide an expression that satisfies the requirement.

Comment: The resolution doesn't change the core logic. Consider a file with dates between 2012 and 2022. If each of your files contains record of a single day, then it would be a good practice to add the date to the filename. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdbjw27QPJQ

Comment: Ingestion source is not necessarily files, it can be code, Spark connector, Event Hub, or query. It seems more efficient to create a mechanism once on your end than make customers create their solutions for each ingestion case (often single-use ones).

Comment: Like in your example, if not that much data between 2012 and 2022, it might be impractical to export data into ~3650 separate files for each day, and rather allow the source to chunk them on node basis or otherwise performance efficient principle. If that feature existed, in the source I would care about what's relevant to the source and in destination – about what's relevant to destination.

Comment: Once again, this doesn't change the core logic. Ingested data might be ordered by the date column you wish to use as *creationTime* or it might be completely cluttered. The ingested system has no control on the ingested records order. You do. The system also has no knowledge on the ingested data, pre ingestion. You do. It is off course theoretically feasible to develop some code that will do something with the data according to some logic, but it would be completely disconnected from the way ingestion works today.

Comment: Putting the theoretical discussion aside - do you need some assistant with your current scenario?

Comment: If you just group by `startofday(ts)` for each ingestion item, can redundant extents be merged later (for future data falling into the same day)?

Comment: It looks like the ingestion system does not want to do much of manipulations with data. How about putting it into the cluster as it works now and then re-ingesting from query? Kind of `append my_table (with creationTimeExpression = startofday(ts)) <| temp_table`.

Comment: Ah sorry, I am good with my current scenario and understand how to do that with the existing capabilities, just hoped there was more optimal way... Thanks for confirming!